# Уровень вложенности для изображений в вебпаке

Tags: изображения, webpack, img

Всем привет.
Суть проблемы есть в названии, опишу ситуацию подробнее.
Начну с описания билда, который у меня работает.
Вот такая структура папок в дев-режиме:

```
src>css
src>images
src>pages>about/index.html
src>pages>index/index.html
```

В html-файлах изображения подключаются следующим образом:

```
<img src=<%=require("../../images/avatar.png")%>
```

После сборки я получаю в папке dist:

```
about.html
index.html
src>images
```

И все работает прекрасно, но есть одно но.

Суть вопроса вот в чем.
Я хотел чтобы после сборки билда index.html оставался наверху, а about.html попадал в папку about. То есть:

```
index.html
about/index.html
src>images
```

Настроить сборку не проблема, всего лишь поменять пути и названия в "new HtmlWebpackPlugin" кроме одного: при такой сборке в папке about абсолютно не грузятся изображения, что бы я ни делал, как бы ни прописывал пути, в index.html изображения есть, а в about/index.html изображений нет, они не грузятся. Почему-то им прописывается адрес about/src/images.

Просьба подсказать что я делаю не так. Вот мой webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
// подключаем плагин
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
// создаем переменную для development-сборки
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/js/index.js',
        saved: './src/js/saved.js',
        about: './src/js/about.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'src/js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ // тут описываются правила
            test: /\.js$/, // регулярное выражение, которое ищет все js файлы
            use: { loader: "babel-loader" }, // весь JS обрабатывается пакетом babel-loader
            exclude: /node_modules/ // исключает папку node_modules
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        // you can specify a publicPath here
                        // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
                        publicPath: '../../',
                        hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                    },
                },
                'css-loader',
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg)$/,
            use: [
                'file-loader?name=./src/images/[name].[ext]',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: {
                        mozjpeg: {
                            progressive: true,
                            quality: 65
                        },
                        optipng: {
                            enabled: false,
                        },
                        pngquant: {
                            quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                            speed: 4
                        },
                        bypassOnDebug: true,
                        disable: true,
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=./src/vendor/fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'src/css/[name].[contenthash].css'
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/gi,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                preset: ['default'],
            },
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false, // стили НЕ нужно прописывать внутри тегов
            hash: true, // для страницы нужно считать хеш
            template: './src/pages/index/index.html', // откуда брать образец для сравнения с текущим видом проекта
            filename: 'index.html' // имя выходного файла, то есть того, что окажется в папке dist после сборки
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './src/pages/saved/index.html',
            filename: 'saved.html'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './src/pages/about/index.html',
            filename: 'about.html'
        }),
        new WebpackMd5Hash(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: на сколько же guip проще...сорри за офтоп

Answer (score 0):

```
src="../<%=require("путь")%>"
```

Несколько часов гугления не выдали мне ни намека что так можно было... Оставлю, может кому пригодится.